sensitivity analysis from optimal tableau table?
I'm studying from my final exam for operation research course and I'm trying to solve variety of sensitivity analysis problem like the one below. I understand the algebraic method of the simplex method but with tableau I'm still struggling. If would appreciate if anyone can help me understand the below problem and help me how to solve the problem from the optimal tableau using algebraic formulas.

My solution:
I'm following the book Linear Programming and Network Flows and exercises problems from Chapter 6.However, I don't feel confident with my approach, so any help pointing out my mistake and guiding me is appreciated.


Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Is your question about a., b. or c.? The more specific you answer is, the better is the answer.

@callculus42 I have attached my approach to the problem. Thank you.
